# How to change the Size of the ListBox of the datePicker in GWT?

Tags: css, gwt

I am building a mobile website and thus I have a need to many all GWT Gui to become bigger.

For example, my css in my gwt mobile app is like this:

```
.myNormalMobileFont{
    font-size: 500%;
}

.myNormalLargeFont{
    font-size: 700%;
 }
```

And Here is Css code of DateBox and DatePicker

```
.gwt-DateBox {
  padding: 15px 16px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-top: 3px solid #999;
  font-size: 500%;
}
.gwt-DateBox input {
  width: 8em;
}
.dateBoxFormatError {
  background: #ffcccc;
}
.dateBoxPopup {
}

.gwt-DatePicker {
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  border-top:3px solid #999;
  cursor: default;
}
.gwt-DatePicker td,
.datePickerMonthSelector td:focus {
  outline: none;
}
.datePickerDays {
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
}
.datePickerDay,
.datePickerWeekdayLabel,
.datePickerWeekendLabel {
  font-size: 255%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 12px;
  outline: none;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#333;
  border-right: 3px solid #EDEDED;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EDEDED;
}
.datePickerWeekdayLabel,
.datePickerWeekendLabel {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0px 12px 6px;
  cursor: default;
  color:#666;
  font-size:210%;
  font-weight:normal;
}
.datePickerDay {
  padding: 12px 21px;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.datePickerDayIsWeekend {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}
.datePickerDayIsFiller {
  color: #999;
  font-weight:normal;
}
.datePickerDayIsValue {
  background: #d7dfe8;
}
.datePickerDayIsDisabled {
  color: #AAAAAA;
  font-style: italic;
}
.datePickerDayIsHighlighted {
  background: #F0E68C;
}
.datePickerDayIsValueAndHighlighted {
  background: #d7dfe8;
}
.datePickerDayIsToday {
  padding: 3px;
  color: #fff;
  background: url(images/hborder.png) repeat-x 0px -2607px;
}

.datePickerMonthSelector {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 3px 0 15px 0;
  background: #fff;
}
td.datePickerMonth {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-size: 300%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #333;
}
.datePickerPreviousButton,
.datePickerNextButton {
  font-size: 360%;
  line-height: 1em;
  color: #3a6aad;
  cursor: hand;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0px 12px;
  outline: none;
}
```

After that, the GuiLookLike this
[image]

Ass u can see the Text inside the Year and Month listbox is very small, so how to style them to make them bigger?, probally using font-size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```css
.gwt-DatePicker .gwt-ListBox {
    font-size: 200%;
}
```

Works if I apply it to the [GWT Showcase](http://samples.gwtproject.org/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDatePicker):

[image]